# Render data in a table on a Django template from multiple tables after filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and any help on my query is appreciated. I am trying to create an inventory portal and want to display summary information in the template as a table.

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
   location_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
   ....< other attributes >

class Rack(models.Model):
   location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   rack_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ....< other attributes >

class Equipment(models.Model):
   rack_id = models.ForeignKey(Rack,on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
   make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ....< other attributes >
```

**My query**
There are several equipments installed **on a rack** (such as Comms equip, Processing equip, etc.,) which in turn is available **on a location**. I want to render summary information onto a template where the first column should be location_name, the second column the count of comms equipment in that location, and the third column count of processing equip, and so on.

```
| Location | Comms Equip | Processing Equip |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| Loc1     | 5           | 8                |
| Loc2     | 2           | 10               |
```

I can obtain the first column by:

**views.py**

```
location = Location.objects.all()
context = {'location': location, }
return render(request, 'appname/summary.html', context)
```

**summary.html**

```
{% for x in location %}
{{ x.location_name }}
```

For second and subsequent columns, I need to filter with a particular location ID which I am unable to obtain with the context available in the views. Hence for the first column it is not with any specific location ID but for rest of the columns, it is with a specific ID (such as count of comms equip with location ID 1) which is where I am struggling. Aplogize if this question is naive but I tried to search for this but was unable to understand any response which answers my question. Thanks.